# Accept only an input of 1 or 2 in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a program that asks for a users input via `set /p var=` but have the problem that the user may input something other then 1 or 2, which is not what I want from them.

I am fully aware I could use a multitude of if statements to check for ONLY 1 or 2, and then just go back to the question and ask again if they don't input a 1 or 2, but I would have to use A TON of labels (`:start`).

If anyone could suggest a way in which I could just force a 1 or 2 response that would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: `choice /c:12` is how. See `Choice /?`. Your problem is that you use stackoverflow as a reference. Read the actual reference.

Comment: Thanks dude, sorry, I didn't realise that there was an actual command in place just for that. I'll be sure to research further next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"choice /c:12 is how. See Choice /?." - Noodles

Thanks for the help!